# Concatenating an array with itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement `Array.repeat`, so

```
[3].repeat(4) // yields
=> [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

... and is driving me crazy.

Tried with this:

```
Array::repeat = (num)->
  array = new Array
  for n in [0..num]
    array.concat(this)
  array
```

But `[3].repeat(x)` always returns `[]`. Where I'm screwing it up? Or is there a better approach do this?

**Final result:**

```
Array::repeat = (num)->
  array = new Array
  return array if num < 1
  for n in [1..num]
    array = array.concat(this)
  array

['a'].repeat(5)
=> ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: No; it's CoffeeScript.

Comment: Its coffescript. It can be compiled to javascript.

Comment: Why are you cloning the original array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`array.concat` returns a new array and does not modify the existing one.

You need to write

```
array = array.concat(dup)
```

Alternatively, you can use `push()`, which does modify the original array:

```
array.push.apply(array, dup)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple:

```
function repeat(array, n){
    var out = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        out = out.concat(array);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Or prototyping:

```
Array.prototype.repeat = function(n){
    var out = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        out = out.concat(this);
    }
    return out;
}
```

That's native JS, not sure how you'd do that in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how function should look like:

```
Array.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    if(count==null||1*count!=count)  //check for cerrect count
        return this.valueOf(); 
    var length = this.length;     //Length
    var return = this.valueOf();  //0 repats equals in the same array
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {  //Repeating the count
      for(var j=0; j<length; j++) {
        return.push(this[j]);
      }
    }
}
```